# Conflict with interceptor and modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dashboard which you can access only through a login page. I've created a login component imported in the app main module and a lazy-loading module for the dashboard itself.

I've created an interceptor for the dashboard's routes to set the headers with the token after logged in, importing it in the providers of this lazy-loading module. However, it also intercepts in the login route, despite it's configure in the dashboard module, not in the main one.

So, if I get an error from the backend when logging in (such as 401 - Wrong credentials), it shows the toast error from the interceptor.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { LoginComponent } from "./components/login/login.component";
import { MaterialModule } from "./material/material.module";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ToastrModule } from "ngx-toastr";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { LoginComponent } from "./components/login/login.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "./guards/auth.guard";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./components/dashboard/dashboard.module").then(
        (m) => m.DashboardModule
      ),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "/dashboard", pathMatch: "full" },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**dashboard.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component";
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from "./dashboard-routing.module";
import { ForbiddenComponent } from "./components/forbidden/forbidden.component";
import { SidenavComponent } from "./components/sidenav/sidenav.component";
import { SidenavService } from "./services/sidenav.service";
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ToastrModule } from "ngx-toastr";
import { TokenInterceptor } from "src/app/interceptors/token.interceptor";
import { DashboardComponent } from "./dashboard.component";
import { ToolbarComponent } from "./components/toolbar/toolbar.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    ForbiddenComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    SidenavComponent,
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule, DashboardRoutingModule, ToastrModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [
    SidenavService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./components/notifications/notifications.module').then(
            (m) => m.NotificationsModule
          )
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

**token.interceptor.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, catchError, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const token = this.auth.accessToken;

    if (!!token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            this.toastr.warning(
              "Try to login again",
              "Session has expired"
            );
            this.router.navigate(["login"]);
          }
        }
        return throwError((err: any) => new Error(err));
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add your route config to the question?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors are running on every request. They are not bound to a route or specific module, even though your declare it in a specific module. After your `DashboardModule` has been lazy loaded it will intercept every request you send. If you want behavior only tied to a specific route you should use route guards instead.

But I think in your case (if I understood correctly what the desired behavior would be) you can change the interceptor logic so it only will handle the requests with an Authorization header and simply forward the other requests directly to the next handler. I'd suggest to change the logic of the interceptor like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, catchError, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const token = this.auth.accessToken;
    
    // If no token, simply forward the request to next handler and return the result.
    if (!token) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    // If there is a token, add it to the request and handle potential 401 response
    const clonedRequest = request.clone({
      setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });
    return next.handle(clonedRequest).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            this.toastr.warning(
              "Try to login again",
              "Session has expired"
            );
            this.router.navigate(["login"]);
          }
        }
        // throw the original error
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

So the difference is that in this case the 401 error handling will not be added to requests without a token (like the login request) but only to the requests that have an Authorization header with a bearer token added.

Preventing unauthorized requests to be sent to the server from within the `DashboardModule` should be done with a route guard, but it looks like you got this part already covered with your `AuthGuard`.

---

**Note:** *I changed the `throwError` logic as well, by wrapping the error in another `Error` class like you do you might unexpectedly break other interceptors or application logic expecting an error of type `HttpErrorResponse`.*